# add letter to to string in objective c if statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablestring

Hello below is the code i am using

```
currentCardDisplayed = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [[cardsShuffled objectAtIndex:currentCard-1] substringToIndex:[[cardsShuffled objectAtIndex:currentCard-1] length]-1]];

NSString *rule;

if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"e"] isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"2"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink2";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"3"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink3";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"4"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink4";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"5"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink5";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"6"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink6";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"7"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink7";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"8"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink8";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"9"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink9";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"0"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink10";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"k"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drinkjack";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"n"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drinkqueen";
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"g"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drinkking";
}
NSLog(@" %@ ", currentCardDisplayed);
NSLog(@" %@ ", currentCardName);
NSLog(@"%@", rule);
NSLog(@" %@", [cardsShuffled objectAtIndex:currentCard-1]);
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rules" message:rule delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[alert show];
```

the letters i am trying to add to the end are not getting there.  i remove a letter at first, but then in my if statement i want to check if  i add a different letter to that variable is it equal to the other string.

Can anyone see where i am going wrong

below is the sample output from the nslogs

```
2012-12-11 20:06:50.853 Kings_1.03[4915:c07]  club.png 
2012-12-11 20:06:50.855 Kings_1.03[4915:c07]  club9.png 
2012-12-11 20:06:50.857 Kings_1.03[4915:c07] (null)
2012-12-11 20:06:50.858 Kings_1.03[4915:c07]  club9
```

ANy help is appreciated

Thanking YOu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the .png after you do the if tests. The way you're doing in now, using your example, is to append the 9 to club.png, which gives you club.png9 not club9, so your test is never satisfied.

The easiest way would probably to not append that .png in the first line, and then in your if statements, append both the letter/number and .png, so:

```
}else if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"9.png"]isEqualToString:currentCardName]){
    rule = @"drink9";
```

Comment: wat do you mean exactly, can you give an example of wat you mean.  or is this wat you mean if([[currentCardDisplayed stringByAppendingString:@"e.png"] isEqualToString:currentCardDisplayed]){
        rule = @"drink";
    }

Comment: @AlanFletcher, no, just don't append the .png when you define currentCardDisplayed in that first line, then the tests will work.

Comment: @AlanFletcher, sorry, no that won't work either because you're comparing it to a string that has the .png on the end.